# Agregar Modulos en AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, modal

Hola a Todos (Requiero utilizar Bootstrap pero al parecer Genera Conflictos con AngularJS por lo que estuve investigando y recomiendan utilizar UI-Bootstrp que esta hecho en solo con AngularJS) por lo que estoy intentando implementar este Modulo

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($uibModal, $log, $document) {
  var $ctrl = this;
  $ctrl.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $ctrl.animationsEnabled = true;

  $ctrl.open = function (size, parentSelector) {
    var parentElem = parentSelector ? 
      angular.element($document[0].querySelector('.modal-demo ' + parentSelector)) : undefined;
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $ctrl.animationsEnabled,
      ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
      ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      controllerAs: '$ctrl',
      size: size,
      appendTo: parentElem,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $ctrl.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $ctrl.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };

  $ctrl.openComponentModal = function () {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $ctrl.animationsEnabled,
      component: 'modalComponent',
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $ctrl.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $ctrl.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('modal-component dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };

  $ctrl.openMultipleModals = function () {
    $uibModal.open({
      animation: $ctrl.animationsEnabled,
      ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title-bottom',
      ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body-bottom',
      templateUrl: 'stackedModal.html',
      size: 'sm',
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.name = 'bottom';  
      }
    });

    $uibModal.open({
      animation: $ctrl.animationsEnabled,
      ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title-top',
      ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body-top',
      templateUrl: 'stackedModal.html',
      size: 'sm',
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.name = 'top';  
      }
    });
  };

  $ctrl.toggleAnimation = function () {
    $ctrl.animationsEnabled = !$ctrl.animationsEnabled;
  };
});

// Please note that $uibModalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $uibModal service used above.

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($uibModalInstance, items) {
  var $ctrl = this;
  $ctrl.items = items;
  $ctrl.selected = {
    item: $ctrl.items[0]
  };

  $ctrl.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close($ctrl.selected.item);
  };

  $ctrl.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});

// Please note that the close and dismiss bindings are from $uibModalInstance.

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').component('modalComponent', {
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  bindings: {
    resolve: '<',
    close: '&',
    dismiss: '&'
  },
  controller: function () {
    var $ctrl = this;

    $ctrl.$onInit = function () {
      $ctrl.items = $ctrl.resolve.items;
      $ctrl.selected = {
        item: $ctrl.items[0]
      };
    };

    $ctrl.ok = function () {
      $ctrl.close({$value: $ctrl.selected.item});
    };

    $ctrl.cancel = function () {
      $ctrl.dismiss({$value: 'cancel'});
    };
  }
});
```

lo estoy tratando de implementar de la Siguiente Manera en mi App (Modulo Principal)

```js
    angular.module('App', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap.demo'])
```

Sin embargo no logro ver cual es mi error y no esta funcionando en la Consola no me generar ningun error, les dejo el link de UI-Bootstrap en el Apartado del Modal viene un ejemplo de como funciona

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal

y aqui un ejemplo sin tantos controles
http://plnkr.co/edit/3p1rXAymd7BilyklgxKy?p=preview

PD: el codigo html esta tal cual esta en el ejemplo ..

Comment: Es que no me genera ningun error ; simplemente no funciona el unico que tube fue que no estaba Registrado mi controlador pero ese lo solucione

Comment: y por consola no te arroja nada?

Comment: nada de nada de hecho tngo en mi App principal otro controlador y este esta trabajando perfectamente con http pero el modal no funciona para nada ..

Comment: entonces estas llamando mal la funcion

Comment: Implemente el codigo tal cual esta en el ejemplo agregando lo del HTML con su respectivo controlador, y agregue el el modulo a mi modulo principal como te comente en la planteacion de la pregunta  y el *.js que contiene a dicho modulo también esta agregado en el html .. (muchas gracias por tus respues .. espero podamos llegar ala solucion XD)

Answer (score 0):

Después de estar revisando por un buen rato por Internet decidí a descargar versiones anteriores de toda la Librería UI-Bootstrap exactamente con la v1.5.3 y sus respectivos módulos para esta version y logre hacerlo funcionar, al parecer las versiones actuales de AngularJS y/o UI-Bootstrap están funcionando de manera estable con esta version, les dejo el enlace de descarga ..

https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.3/angular-1.5.3.zip

Comment: Por favor Marca como cerrada la pregunta cuando trabajas con nom y paquetes las actualizaciones son muy rápidas por el es ideal que tú componer.json tenga la versión exacta con la que trabajas